# Encoding difference between Python and C

Tags: python, string, binary, encode

I am trying to save some data obtained in Python to a binary file that one could read using C. The problem is that strings in Python and C are encoded differently, which creates unnecessary mess while reading the file.

Create a file using Python:

```
from array import array

string = "test"
text_array = array('u', list(string))

output_file = open('test_file.bin', 'wb')
text_array.tofile(output_file)
output_file.close()
```

Read the same file using C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file_pointer = fopen("test_file.bin", "rb");
    char *symbol;
    fread(symbol, sizeof(char), 16, file_pointer);
    char * text = (char * ) malloc( 4 * sizeof(char) );
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) text[j] = symbol[4 * j];
    printf("%s \n", text);
    fclose(file_pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to save the text "test" using Python in a way that it takes 4 bytes, not 16 bytes, and so the C-code for reading would be cleaner.

I have tried to convert Unicode to ANSII in Python, but it is not clear how to proceed further with writing.

Comment: PSA: You don't need to [cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Is the use of `array` an important component of this?

Comment: Don't convert the string to a `u` array. That corresponds to `wchar_t` in C.

Comment: Use `b` or `B`.

Comment: you are *explicitly using unicode* wtih an `array.array`... why are you doing that? don't do that if you don't want that.

Comment: Also, `u` is deprecated.